# A certain colony of bacteria

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

A certain colony of bacteria is growing at 4% daily. If the culture of bacteria 
has a population of 4,000 today, what will it be after 10 days?

Comment: If the population on day $n$ is $p_n$ the population on day $n+1$ will be $1.04\times p_n$. Then as the population on day $0$ (today) is $4000$ the population after 10 days will be $1.04^{10} \times p_0=1.04^{10} \times 4000$

Comment: Math isn't as difficult as some people believe, but that is not to say that it doesn't require effort.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have population of $P_0$ on day $0$:
day-$0$: $P_0$

and on day-$1$ you have
day-$1$: $P_1 = P_0 + 0.04 P_0 = 1.04\times P_0$

day-$2$: $P_2 = P_1 + 0.04 P_1 = 1.04 P_1 =1.04(1.04P_0) = 1.04^2 P_0$

day-$3$: $ P_3 = P_2 + 0.04 P_2 = 1.04 P_2 = 1.04(1.04^2P_0) = 1.04^3 P_0$

so on day $n$ you have

$ P_n = P_{n-1} + 0.04 P_{n-1} = 1.04 P_{n_1} =1.04(1.04^{n-1}P_0) = 1.04^n P_0$

Set $n=10$ and $P_0=4000$ and you have answer!

Comment: Why the answer is not useful?

Comment: Would like to see $$P_0 + 0.04P_0 = 1P_0+0.04P_0=(1+0.04)P_0$$ +1 though.